# Vertex of a pentagon-Does the algorithm always stop?

Tags: algorithms, contest-math, invariance

To each vertex of a pentagon,we assign an integer $x_{i}$ with sum $s=\sum x_{i}>0$.
If x,y,z are the numbers assigned to 3 successive vertices and if $y<0$,then we replace $(x,y,z)$ by $(x+y,-y,y+z)$.This step is repeated as long as there is a y<0.Decide if the algorithm always stops.

Comment: If you're not willing to do any part of the work yourself but want random strangers on the internet to provide you with a "detailed solution", then why are you even in the contest?

Comment: Well I found this question in a book.I tried a lot,but couldn't figure out a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is IMO 1986 Q3.

Consider the  monovariant $S=\sum_{i=1}^{5}{(x_{i+2}-x_i)^2}$, where $x_6=x_1, x_7=x_2$.

WLOG suppose we perform an operation to get from $(x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4, x_5)$ to $(x_1+x_2, -x_2, x_2+x_3, x_4, x_5)$, and $S$ changes to $S'$. Then

\begin{align}
S-S' &=(x_3-x_1)^2+(x_4-x_2)^2+(x_5-x_3)^2+(x_1-x_4)^2+(x_2-x_5)^2 \\
& -(x_3-x_1)^2-(x_4+x_2)^2-(x_5-x_2-x_3)^2-(x_1+x_2-x_4)^2-(-x_2-x_5)^2 \\
&=-2x_2(x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4+x_5) \\
& <0
\end{align}

since $s=\sum{x_i}>0$ and $x_2<0$.

Now $S$ is clearly a non-negative integer, and is strictly decreasing in each step, so the algorithm will always stop.

There is another solution using a different monovariant [here](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/~asdas/imo/imo/isoln/isoln863.html).

Comment: Thanks!Didn't realize it was an IMO question though.