# An Extension to a problem of IMO 1986

Tags: combinatorics, contest-math

To each vertex of a pentagon, we assign an integer $x_i$ with sum $$s=\sum x_i>0$$ If $x$, $y$, $z$ are the numbers assigned to three successive vertices and if $y<0$ , then we replace $(x, y, z)$    by $(x+y, -y, z+y)$. This step is repeated as long as there is a $y<0$. Decide if the algorithm always stop .

I know this question is already asked, but my question is, *how much steps are needed until stop*??

Comment: The $gcd$ of adjacent pairs are unchanged. So I guess the answer is connected to Archimedes' algorithm?

Comment: The "official" solution to IMO 1986 A3 is to come up with some expression $M(x)\in\mathbb{N}$ (the choice of $M$ is not unique) such that each step strictly reduces $M(x)$.  So you have a rather slliy bound $\leq M(x)$ steps.

Comment: Doesn’t https://math.stackexchange.com/a/338733/42969 provide an explicit bound on the number of steps?

Comment: No, it doesn't....

Comment: This post just ensures that algorithm stops

Comment: @Marx_dreamer it does bound it, see my comment above or my answer below.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).  For equations, please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 2):

Consider $M$ to be the sum of squares of the difference across diagonals (I believe it is more elegant than the one proposed [here](/a/2868142/592552) by @Batominovski), i.e.,
$$
M(x)=(x_1-x_3)^2+(x_2-x_4)^2+(x_3-x_5)^2+(x_4-x_1)^2+(x_5-x_2)^2
$$
Then $M(x)\in\mathbb{N}$, and if $(x'_{i-2},x'_{i-1},x'_i,x'_{i+1},x'_{i+2})=(x_{i-2},x_{i-1}+x_i,-x_i,x_{i+1}+x_i,x_{i+2})$ (subscripts interpreted mod 5) we have
$$
M(x')=M(x)+2sx_i
$$
(see the [solution](/a/338733/592552) by @IvanLoh as @MartinR linked in the comments for details) so for $x_i<0$ this process strictly decreases $M$.  So at most $\lfloor M/(2s)\rfloor$ steps are needed.

Comment: I didn't got that how max. no. of steps is M/(2s)??

Comment: Because each step decreases $M$ by at least $2s$ (note $s$ being invariant under the operation), and $M$ has to remain nonnegative.

Comment: But according to user629660, it should be no. of negative elements in S(defined in post).

Comment: @Marx_dreamer: note the words "*at most*"

Comment: @MartinR: $s$ is invariant since $(x+y)+(-y)+(z+y)=x+y+z$.

Comment: Your approach is really appreciable..

Answer (score 1):

Consider a finite miultiset $S$ of all sums defined by $$s(i, j)= \sum_{k=i}^{j-1}x_k,$$ where $1≤i≤5$ and $j>i$.

A *multiset* is a set which can have equal elements.

In this set, all elements, except for one, either remain invariant or are switched with others. Only $s(4, 5)=x_4$; however, if $x_4<0$ then we have $s(4, 5) = -x_4$. Thus, exactly one negative element of $S$ becomes positive for each step. Since $s > 0$, $S$ contains only finitely many negative elements. The number of steps until stop is equal to the number of negative elements of $S$. We see that the $x_i$ need not be integers.

Comment: I think you need to allow the sums $s(i,j)$ to wrap cyclically; for example, let $s(4,3)=x_4+x_5+x_1+x_2$. There are $20$ possible cyclically consecutive sums; $5$ choices for $i$, $4$ for $j$ such that $i\neq j$. Each move makes a negative sum positive (of the form $s(i,i+1)=x_i$), and permutes the others, so after at most $20$ moves all sums (and therefore all numbers) are positive.

Comment: MikeEarnest: Not wrap cyclically like $s(4,3)$, but allow arbitrarily large $j$ (and interpret subscripts mod 5).  Yes, the edit by @VictoriaM misinterpreted the very badly phrased original.

Comment: @user10354138 Oh, I see it now!